# how to verify in assertj that elements are one of

Tags: assertj

I can't find how to do check with assertj the following (which is very common):

Suppose I have:

```
 result1 = {"AAA", "BBB"}
 result2 = {"DDD"}
```

I want to check the values in result is one of these:

```
String[] valid = String[]{"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
```

using assertj, whould be something as:

```
assertThat(result1).xxxx(valid);
assertThat(result2).xxxx(valid);
```

So that result1 would pass check, but result2 not.

contains() does not work (it checks that result contains all valid elements)

I don't want have to create a custom condition for this kind of checking

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wtite it the other way around:

```
assertThat(valid).contains(result1);
assertThat(valid).contains(result2);
```

If you insist on having the *result* on the left and *valid* on the right side, you can use:

```
assertThat(result1).isSubsetOf(Arrays.asList(valid));
assertThat(result2).isSubsetOf(Arrays.asList(valid));
```

Or, why not to define the *valid* as a set, rather than an array?

```
Set<String> valid = Sets.newHashSet("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"); //Sets comes from google guava
assertThat(result1).isSubsetOf(valid);
assertThat(result2).isSubsetOf(valid);
```

Comment: I agree, see http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#isSubsetOf-java.lang.Iterable-

What is missing is the possibility to pass an array/varargs in isSubsetOf, I have created an inssue for that (https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/548)